# Why is Ebrantil (Urapidil) not FDA approved?

Tags: blood-pressure, heart-rate, fda

Ebtrantil (Urapidil) is commonly used as an antihypertensive in Europe, [also due to its additive interaction with other antihypertensives, and less likely to alter the heart rate compared to similar alternatives](https://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00003495-199856050-00016).

However, the [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urapidil) points out that it is not FDA approved in the U.S. What are the FDA's concerns?

Comment: It doesn't appear in the [National Drug Code Directory](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ndc/index.cfm), which suggests that it's never been submitted to the FDA.